# LEFT JOIN complication for child rows that don't exist or if exist, pick one with a specific value

Tags: mysql

Sorry for my bad english. I have two tables: tblemployees (employeeid) and tbloffices: officeid,employeecode,activeposition

Basically, tbloffices contains list of offices in a company the employee has ever worked in. He/she can work only in one office at a given time (so activeposition can be 1 only per employee once). Some employees can have record in tbloffices but with no active office currently. Some employees might not have a record in tbloffies at all (waiting for relocation for e.g.).

My query needs is: return employeeid along with the activeposition=1 if it exists. Else, return the latest position. If no records exist, return NULL of course:

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT employeeid, officeid, activeposition 
  FROM tblemployees 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbloffices 
    ON(tbloffices.employeecode = tblemployees.employeeid) 
 GROUP 
    BY employeeid
```

The query does work for rows with no reference in tbloffices. How do i return one record per employee in the fashion I want? I already tried:

```
(officeid is NULL OR activeposition=1)
```

but that fails for employees with record but no active position.

Comment: You need to provide `sample data` and the `expected result` from that data. The data should be in a format we can use to populate tables. This is the fastest route to a successful solution.

Comment: One would not expect an employee to appear in an office table